# How to add html in shorthand if with blade tags

Tags: laravel

How do i add a span tag around the $product->category->name in one line?

```
       <td>{{$product->category ? $product->category->name : 'category not known'}}</td>
```

```
      <span class="badge bg-danger">{{$product->category->name}}</span><br>
```

Comment: `{!! '<span class="badge bg-danger">' . $product->category->name . '</span>'  !!}`will output html, if that is your question.

Comment: no i want something like this:

`  <td>{{$product->category ? {!! '<span class="badge bg-danger">' . $product->category->name . '</span>'  !!} : 'category not known'}}</td>`

Comment: Thats an echo inside an echo, check my answer.

Comment: Like you have done?

Comment: thank you just what i need was hard to search for answer to this problem

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you have a blade echo in your blade echo, just remove that one and add '( ... )':

```
<td>{!! $product->category ?  ('<span class="badge bg-danger">' . $product->category->name . '</span>') : 'category not known'!!}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You looking for this shorthand?

```
<span class="badge bg-danger">{{$product->category->name ?? 'category not known'}}</span><br>
```

This is called the "null coalescing operator"

> It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.